# Why OpenCL refuses to work on compatible hardware under Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opencl, ubuntu-20.04, mesa

Well, I need a help from someone who has some experience using AMD GPUs on Linux.

I have AMD ATI Radeon HD 8550M. It supports OpenCL 1.2. And AMD ATI Radeon R3 Graphics which supports OpenCL 2.0. I have latest Mesa driver installed.

And here's a question: why *clinfo* displays "0"?

Not to mention that I can't use it in any software.

Comment: Sorry to say - the old GPU needs an old AMD driver, and this driver needs an old Ubuntu version. So, if you need to keep the Ubuntu version, you'll need to upgrade the GPU. If you want to keep the GPU, you'll need to downgrade the Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

The old `opencl-mesa` runtime seems broken. Try `opencl-amd` or the [latest official drivers](https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-8000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-8550m-series-gpu) instead.

Comment: Uh... How can I try it? It's impossible to install it using apt, and official drivers making my system go black (IDK why).

Comment: Depending on your Linux distro and package installer that might not be available. I've tested `opencl-amd` on Arch Linux with `yay`. If the package is not available, install the latest drivers from the AMD website.

Comment: And this is impossible, cause for some reason official AMD drivers are faulty on my configuration. Any other ways to install opencl-amd on Ubuntu?

Comment: Tried to install it using amdgpu-install --usecase=opencl --no-dkms. It installed, and it displays in clinfo now, but still refuses to work.

Answer (score 0):

For most people and most practical purposes, AMD GPUs are not supported on Linux.
There is no "official" (by which I mean GPL2 or GPL3) driver, and AFAIK never has been, for AMD.
If you happen to be running one of the few versions of Ubuntu that the proprietary drivers support, and if you plan to never upgrade your Ubuntu version, and if you accept the risk of running proprietary software on your computer, then you can use the proprietary driver.